# Finding formula to count number of arrays of the numbers $1, 2, 3, \ldots, n$ in which an entry is in the top row or has an element directly above it

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

Consider the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$.  In how many ways can the elements be arranged in an array such that an entry is either placed in the top row or immediately below another entry in the array?

1:
    1

2:

```
1 2   2 1   1   2
            2   1
```

3:

```
1 2 3   1 3 2   2 1 3   2 3 1   3 1 2   3 2 1

1 2   1 2   2 1   2 1   1 3   1 3   3 1   3 1   2 3   2 3   3 2   3 2 
3       3   3       3   2       2   2       2   1       1   1       1

1   1   2   2   3   3
2   3   1   3   1   2
3   2   3   1   2   1
```

4: would take a long time to format and layout here

example $n=5$:

```
1 2 3
    4
    5
```

which results in

```
1!, 2!+2!, 3!+3!+3!+3!, ...
1,  4,     24,          ...
```

Originally, I came up with something like:

(wrong) $f(c) = \sum_{n=1}^{c}  (c!)$, which gives: $1,4,18,96$

Then I came up with this:

$f\left(c\right)=2^{\left(c-1\right)}c!$

which results in the same answer $1, 4, 24, 192, \ldots$, but I don't know if its correct beyond that point up to infinity, and I of course don't want to list them out because even $f(4)=192$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: If I understand the rules correctly, for the $n = 4$ case, you could have a row of four entries; a column of four entries; two rows, with two entries each; two rows, with the top row having three entries and the second row having one; three rows, with the top row having three entries and the remaining two rows each having one entry in the same column as one of the entries in the top row.  If that is the case, check your value for $f(4)$.

Comment: You are required to permute all of those steps for the n=4 case, so each case you listed+the many you missed would be 4!, and from that, i believe the n=4 case would be (2^3)*(4!) from my function giving 192. Also, as seen in the case n=3, when there are two number in row one and 1 number in row two, you can move the number in row 2 to be below any of those in row one.

Comment: I accounted for that.  What I was saying is that your value for $f(4)$ is too small.

Comment: I now realize that I misstated the last case: It should have been three rows, with the top row having two entries and one of the columns having three entries, which means your value for $f(4)$ is correct.

Comment: I added an example n=5 case, I don't know if my formula accounts for it though.

Comment: I edited your question for clarity.  Please make sure that it says what you intended.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  The question might be clearer if you wrote the arrays in matrix format, with commas between matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In how many ways can the elements of the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$ be written in an array such that an entry not in the top row always has an element immediately above it?

Your proposed answer $2^{n - 1}n!$ is correct.

Notice that each column corresponds to a nonempty subset of $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$.   For instance, in your example, 
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
  &   & 4\\
  &   & 5
\end{matrix}
the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ is decomposed into the sequence of subsets 
$\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3, 4, 5\}$.  Therefore, each such array corresponds to expressing the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$ as a sequence of mutually disjoint nonempty subsets whose union is $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$.

The number of columns is the number of [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $n$, that is, the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of a sequence of positive integers.
There are $2^{n - 1}$ such sequences.  For instance, if $n = 5$, there are $2^{5 - 1} = 2^4 = 16$ compositions.  They are 
\begin{align*}
5 & = 5\\
  & = 4 + 1\\
  & = 1 + 4\\
  & = 3 + 2\\
  & = 2 + 3\\
  & = 3 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 1 + 3 + 1\\
  & = 1 + 1 + 3\\
  & = 2 + 2 + 1\\
  & = 2 + 1 + 2\\
  & = 1 + 2 + 2\\
  & = 2 + 1 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 1 + 2 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 1 + 1 + 2 + 1\\
  & = 1 + 1 + 1 + 2\\
  & = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
\end{align*} 
To see why, write $n$ as a row of $n$ ones.  There are $n - 1$ spaces between successive ones in the row.
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square \cdots \square 1 \square 1$$
A composition is determined by deciding whether to fill each such space with an addition sign or to leave it blank.   For instance, if $n = 5$, the four decisions fill, fill, blank, blank yield
$$1 + 1 + 1 1 1$$
which corresponds to the composition $1 + 1 + 3$, which means we place one entry in the first column, one entry in the second column, and three entries in the third column.

For each of the possible $2^{n - 1}$ compositions that tell us where we can place the numbers in the array (how many elements to place in each subset in the sequence of nonempty subsets), we can arrange the $n$ numbers in those spaces in $n!$ ways.  Hence, the number of ways the elements of the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$ can be arranged in an array such that an entry not in the top row always has an entry immediately above it (the number of sequences of mutually disjoint nonempty subsets whose union is the whole set) is $2^{n - 1}n!$.

Comment: That all makes sense 100%, thanks.